# Django form: restore predefined field value in clean method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django form I need to perform different field values comparisons (+ some additional checks). If all of these conditions are met I want to raise error and inform user that he can't perform this operation. Right now I'm doing it in `clean` method and code looks like these:

```
        if self.instance.foo != cleaned_data['foo'] and \
            Bar.objects.filter(baz=self.instance.id).count():
        cleaned_data['foo'] = self.instance.foo
        raise forms.ValidationError("You can't change it")
```

That's working fine, but I'd also like to reject the change and restore previous value (before the update). The assignment `cleaned_data['foo'] = self.instance.foo` obviously is not working because cleaned_data is not being returned due to raising ValidationError. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that you can access fields' values via `self.data`. So I ended up doing `self.data['foo'] = self.instance.foo` and it's working now.

Comment: This QueryDict instance is immutable
i get this error